# Using regular expressions in R to detect one or two repeated characters within a class of characters

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to detect one or more repeated characters within a class of characters, but not a combination of unique characters within the class. In the example below, we're looking for instances of *p*'s, *t*'s, or *k*'s before an *r*.  All three words satisfy the regular expression below, but I would like to exclude cases like *be**kt**ri* where we have two different consonants before *r*.

```
example <- c("betri", "bettri", "bektri")
str_detect(example, "[ptk]r")
```

So *betri* and *bettri* are good, but *bektri* is bad. Any tips?

Comment: I understand it like that: `p`, `k` and `t` can appear one or more times before `r`, but only at the start of a word or after a vowel. If it is so, you may use `str_detect(example, "(?:^|[eyuioa])([ptk])\\1*r")`. If the word can be inside a longer string, `"(?:\\b|[eyuioa])([ptk])\\1*r"`

Comment: If my understand of the question is correct I suggest you add *beptri* and *truck* to `example` and write "*betri*, *bettri* and *truck* are good, but *bektri* and *beptri* are bad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```r
library(stringr)
example <- c("betri", "bettri", "bektri")
str_detect(example, "([ptk])(\\1+)r|([^ptk])([ptk])r")
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

`([ptk])\\1{1}r` matches p, t, or k two times before an r;
(`\\1{1}` matches one character from the preceding group--`([ptk])`;
`([^ptk])([ptk])r` matches a p, t, or k before an r when it is not preceded by a p, t, or k.

You could also generalize to include any consonant that follows that pattern:

```r
library(stringr)
example <- c("betri", "bettri", "bektri", "aepro", "aepo", "aeppro")
str_detect(example, "([[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]])(\\1+)r|([^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]])([[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]])r")
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I don't know R, but do you need the capture groups other than the first? I ran it [here](https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler) with `([ptk])\\1+r|[^ptk][ptk]r` and got the same result. `(?:([ptk])\\1+|[^ptk][ptk])r` may read better (but maybe not).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind `(?<!)` to exclude matches when your letter combinations are preceded by `k`.

```
example <- c("betri", "bettri", "bektri")
str_detect(example, "(?<!k)[ptk]r")
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Edit:
I notice that I misread your post and you need to exclude matches when you have two different consonants before `r`.

Then I would use the following regex: `(?<![^aeuioy])([^aeuioy])\\1?r`. It will match any single or duplicate consonants before `r`, whether it's at the beginning of the word or in the middle of it.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that `r` must be preceded by `p`, `t` or `k`. If the latter character is at the beginning of the line there is a match. If the latter character is not at the beginning of the line, there is a match if it is preceded by itself of by a character other than `p`, `t` or `k`. See my comment on the question which, in effect, asks for a clarification.

Comment: Cary's comment is correct, for my purpose, we need to exclude any combination of non-identical consonants, not just k. But thank you for the help!

Comment: This is exactly what the regex in my edit does and, as opposed to @paqmo's solution, it also works for words starting with two consonants such as "truck".